# No puedo ver las sugerencias de las varibles en css

Tags: vscode

Cuando empiezo a llamar en css las clases como los id y coloco los paréntesis y voy agregar una variable como margin no me sale las sugerencias de los tipos y solo sale el margin por si solo y no así margin: ; . En el siguiente video pueden ver.

- 1= Ya volvi a instalar visual studio code de nuevo.
- 2= Resetea el IntelliSense y nada.
- 3= Incluso instale nuevas extensiones; no se que hacer.

Este es el video para que puedan ver:     https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zttSr9mF4fNF1yyZoMIrR5Z7_hjVpwYI/view?usp=sharing

- 1= Ya volví a instalar visual studio code de nuevo.
- 2= Resetea el IntelliSense y nada.
- 3= Incluso instale nuevas extensiones; no se que hacer.

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.